# Using numbers as matplotlib plot markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 1-D numpy array, which I want to plot and I wanted the plot marker to be a number which shows the location of the element. For example, if my array is `[2.5,4,3]` then I want the plot to have the number 0 at the point (0,2.5), 1 at (1,4) and 2 at (2,3) and so on.

How to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that the use of pylab might be discouraged.

you can call `pylab.text()` in a for loop:

```
import pylab as pl
xs = [0, 1, 2]
ys = [2.5, 4, 3]
pl.plot(xs, ys, "-o")
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    pl.text(x, y, str(x), color="red", fontsize=12)
pl.margins(0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You can directly write text rather than use a marker of text like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = [0, 1, 2]
ys = [2.5, 4, 3]
plt.plot(xs, ys, "-o")
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    plt.text(x, y, str(x), color="red", fontsize=12)
```